# Top Region of Page not clickable

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Curious problem here...the top 80 pixels or so of the header of my website isn't clickable. Any element in the top 80 pixels doesn't respond to hover events or clicks etc. Bringing a link down below this area with a margin-top or something makes it clickable. Even the top half of the logo image isn't clickable while the bottom half is. Really can't figure out why this happening.

The url is at http://www.vapetropolis.ca.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In future try to post questions with specific code examples so future users can easily see what's going on.

That being said, it looks like the `<div class="cms-links">` is covering up the 80px you're talking about. I removed it using the inspector and the problem went away.